# Selecting elements with same class name on the page

Tags: ruby, selenium, scripting, automation, webdriver

I am trying to locate elements having same classes assigned to them all over the page.
I tried using

```
browser.find_element(css:first-child,".formProperty.fpMandatory.fpUpdateable .off .collapsedView.Uncompleted .fpColValue .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector  .integer").send_keys"1000"
```

But, it fails stating syntax error SyntaxError: (irb):87: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>

There are 6 elements assigned with same class on the page and I need to select those and send values into them.

```
<div class="body">
<div class="content">
<div class="view">
<div class="formPropertyBoxDefs">
<div id="tile379" class="formProperty fpCompleted fpMandatory " ktype="formProperty">
<div id="tile381" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty">
<div id="tile381_selector" class="on" fbtype="selector">
<div id="collapsedtile381" class="collapsedView Uncompleted" style="display:block; cursor:default;">
<div id="tile381_collapsed_statusFlyer" class="fpColStatus">
<div class="fpColTitle">
<div class="fpColValue">
<!-- CssName applied only on expanded mode -->
<div id="tile382" class="textFieldValueSelector valueSelector">
<div onmousedown="valueSelectorOnEnter('tile381', $('tile382_input'), 'focus')">
<input id="tile382_input" class="integer" type="text" onchange="setValueSelectorDirty('cpe111');" selector="selector" value=""/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tile383" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty">
<div id="tile385" class="formProperty fpCompleted fpMandatory " ktype="formProperty">
```

Its the above elements which I am trying to select by class selectors.
I am running it in IRB thus, won't require a wait and its not in iframe as we can see above block of code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Abhishekl

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the HTML.  Is each `div` self contained, or is each subsequent `div` contained within the other?  i.e. is this `<div></div><div></div>...<div></div>` or is it `<div><div><div>...</div></div></div>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:first-child` should be part of the selector:

```
browser.find_element(:css,".formProperty.fpMandatory.fpUpdateable .off .collapsedView.Uncompleted .fpColValue .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector  .integer:first-child").send_keys"1000"
```

To select each of the elements, you can use `:nth-child(n)`, where `n` is the count of the item you want to interact with:

```
browser.find_element(:css,".formProperty.fpMandatory.fpUpdateable .off .collapsedView.Uncompleted .fpColValue .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector  .integer:nth-child(1)").send_keys"1000"
browser.find_element(:css,".formProperty.fpMandatory.fpUpdateable .off .collapsedView.Uncompleted .fpColValue .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector  .integer:nth-child(2)").send_keys"200"
```

Note:  `:nth-child(n)` will not work with IE 7 or IE 8.

Hopefully the last edit:

I think you're going to need to use `find_elements()` for this case.

```
elements = browser.find_elements(:css,".formProperty.fpMandatory.fpUpdateable .off .collapsedView.Uncompleted .fpColValue .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector  .integer")

elements[0].send_keys"1000"
elements[1].send_keys"200"
```

Edit to explain the failure of `:nth-child(n)` in this case:

So, your original HTML that you edited in looked like this:

```
<div id="tile381" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile383" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile385" class="formProperty fpCompleted fpMandatory " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile387" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile389" class="formProperty fpMandatory " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile391" class="formProperty fpCompleted fpMandatory " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile393" class="formProperty fpCompleted fpMandatory " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile395" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile397" class="formProperty fpMandatory " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile399" class="formProperty fpMandatory " ktype="formProperty"></div>
```

When I tested `:nth-child(2)`, it worked on this particular HTML.  When I tried `nth-child(3)`, it did not work.

If your HTML looked like this:

```
<div id="tile381" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile383" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile387" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty"></div>
<div id="tile395" class="formProperty fpMandatory fpUpdateable " ktype="formProperty"></div>
```

Then `:nth-child(n)` would work for all four cases that it should match.

Given the structure of your HTML, `find_elements` is the correct approach.

Comment: what command should we specify for second, third, fourth and so on elements.. 
I just tried

`browser.find_element(:css,".formProperty.fpMandatory.fpUpdateable .off .collapsedView.Uncompleted .fpColValue .textFieldValueSelector.valueSelector  .integer:second-child").send_keys"200"`

But it throws syntax error of

ctor  .integer:second-child is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: I tried the second approach and it worked perfectly fine for first element (1) but fails to detect the second element. I made sure again whether the element is surrounded by same classes and yes it is.  What could be wrong?

Comment: @user007 It's difficult to say without seeing the HTML.  At a guess, it could be one of the following:  The second element is not visible, it's inside of a frame or iframe, the second element is displayed after Selenium starts interacting with the page, and would need a wait.

Comment: I have edited my question to include block of elements present in same classes. Its not within an iframe and am running it manually, hence wait won't be required.

Comment: @user007 One more edit, hopefully this addresses your other issue.

Comment: Great, it worked with array approach. BTW how did you decide upon this approach as opposed to earlier. I am a newbie in automation and really need to learn things.

Comment: @user007 I tested the `:nth-child(n)` selector with your original HTML in Chrome, and realized the `div` elements that matched the selector were broken up with `div` elements that did not match the css selector. Apparently `:nth-child(n)` only works if the elements are all one after another.  I think.  Given that was the case, I decided that `find_elements` would be a workable solution for your case.

Comment: Richard, Could you please elaborate, _**div** elements that matched the selector were broken up with div elements that did not match the **css selector**_

Comment: I got your point. Thank you so much Richard for your help. Truly appreciate that!